# How are Wald type tests better asymptotically?

Tags: asymptotics, wald-test

I heard that Wald tests are better asymptotically than other tests. But what does this mean? Does it mean that it's better at testing for population level differences? Is it better for "big data" and high sample sizes?

Comment: What other tests?

Comment: don't know, lr test, score test?

Comment: Those are asymptotically equivalent. I think you'll need to provide more context to the claim, ideally a citation, for your q. to be answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wald test is *asymptotically equivalent* to the likelihood ratio and (Rao) score tests. They are not better. In fact, the likelihood ratio test is the uniformly most powerful test. The score test has the advantage over the other two of 1. not requiring an evaluation of the variance under the alternative hypothesis and 2. being the framework that unifies many popular tests—the Log rank test, Cochran-Mantel Haenszel, and Pearson Chi-square tests are all Score tests.